# Error: "String can not be converted to int" in Java

Tags: java, string, integer

I've tried to write some code with a getter method however at `return` I had a problem

```
public int getNumberOfPages()
 {
   return "Number of pages: " + this.numberOfPages;
 }
```

numberOfPages is declared as an integer. When I compile the code I get this error message "string can not be converted to int". 
How can I fix the problem??
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are returning a String `"Number of pages: " + this.numberOfPages` is String. You have to return `this.numberOfPages`

Comment: What is numberOfPages?

Comment: At the end I expect to see "Number of pages: 100" like this. numberOfPages is just a number will be set by user.

Comment: maybe you need to define your function as returning String instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the method like this:

```
 public String getNumberOfPages()
  {
   return "Number of pages: " + this.numberOfPages;
  }
```

But If you want use a variables named `numberOfPages` and create the `set` and `get` methods like this:

```
 private int numberOfPages ;

public int getNumberOfPages() {
    return numberOfPages;
}

public void setNumberOfPages(int numberOfPages) {
    this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
}
```

Comment: Accually I want to see " Number of pages: 100". The number will be set by user.

Comment: @mrv_ce how you set the number of pages?

Comment: public void setNumberOfPages()
     {
        System.out.println("Please set the number of pages for periodic printed Media");
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfPages = input.nextInt();
        this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
     } I set the mothod like this.

Comment: @mrv_ce ok if you set the value like you said use the code above

Answer (score 3):

The method you declared

```
public int getNumberOfPages()
```

should be returning an `int` type, but you are returning

```
return "Number of pages: " + this.numberOfPages;
```

and the `"Number of pages: "` part is not an `int`, it's a type of `String`.

I guess what you're trying to do is print out the number of pages, so here are two ways of doing it.

**1 Not the best way**

Just change your return type from `int` to `String`

```
class ClassName {
    int numberOfPages = 10;
    public String getNumberOfPages() {
      return "Number of pages: " + numberOfPages;
    }
}

public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassName instanceName = new ClassName();
        System.out.println(instanceName.getNumberOfPages());
    }
}
```

**2 A better way of doing it**

return only the variable `numberOfPages` to your method and add the `"Number of pages: "` part to `println`

```
class ClassName {
    int numberOfPages = 10;
    public int getNumberOfPages() {
      return numberOfPages;
    }
}

public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassName instanceName = new ClassName();
        System.out.println("Number of Pages: " + instanceName.getNumberOfPages());
    }
}
```

This way you can use the `getNumberOfPages()` method later for other things as well.

*Also note that you do not have to use the `this` keyword in your `getNumberOfPages()` method unless there's shadowing going on, but there's clearly no shadowing here.

Comment: In the final, I will use the get method in toString method to obtain a list of information about a media. However, if any info is missing ı should not write it as empty line. If there is no info about number of pages, the line about it should not exist.  To make this I find adding the information to the get method as the easiest way. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

When you return `"Number of pages: " + this.numberOfPages` Java interprets that as a string because there is no numerical way to represent `"Number of pages: "` as an int and Java gives you an error.

If you would like to print `this.numberOfPages` with the text `"Number of pages: "` preceding it, i believe you would want to call the function when outputting the text...

```
System.out.println("Number of pages: " + getNumberOfPages());
```